# Mercurial, updating subrepo location

Tags: mercurial, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

One of my subrepo url got changed and I had to update all my projects to use the new location. I happen to have the working clones of all the projects that use that subrepo.

But what if I didn't have a working copy of one of them, how could I clone that project and update its subrepo url? Is it possible to change to .hgsub without a working copy?

It looks like there is no way to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by [specifying a mapping](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SubrepoRemappingPlan) in the .hgrc file or the .hg/subpaths file.